# Kohana validation 3.3

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-auth

How do I properly validate a submitted form? I've been looking in the documentation on http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/validation and http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/security/validation, the latter also tells me *"This page needs to be reviewed for accuracy by the development team. Better examples would be helpful."*

What I'm trying to achieve is registering a User (the Auth module) I'm not quite sure which one too use and why.

Comment: The first link you posted contains examples on how to validate models.  What more are you looking for?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean? My question is stated, "How do I properly validate a submitted form?" And then I've provided some links that are quite unclear - because the content examples provided are not working, lastly I state that I tend to use the Auth module.

Comment: Validation rules are set in models. When you try to register (create) a new user, validation exceptions will be thrown if there are errors, and you need to catch the exceptions to display the errors. The `action_create` method shows the general method of doing this. What part of that do you need clarification on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/validation
This is how you validate your models

http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/security/validation
And that's how you validate the user input.

I have used both in a few projects after reading the examples on above links and everything worked pretty much fine.